# vue.js - how to stub/mock http request in cypress component test

Tags: vue.js, testing, vue-component, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I have a profile dialog, where it fetches the data of the current user:

ProfileDialog.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
<dialog-base :save-button-action="save" :cancel-button-action="cancelAction" title="Profile"
              :tab-items="['profile', 'car']" @tabidxChanged="tabidxChanged">
    <v-tabs-items v-model="tabsidx">
        <v-tab-item>
            <v-row class="mt-n1">
                <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field
                        v-model="name"
                        label="Name"
                        :rules="notEmptyRule"
                        outlined
                        name="confirm_password"
                        persistent-placeholder
                    ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>  

  ... display other fields

</dialog-base>


</template>

<script>

import DialogBase from "@/components/DialogBase.vue";
import NewCarDialog from "@/components/NewCarDialog";
import {WebsocketClient} from "@/mixins/WebsocketClient";

export default {
    name: 'profile-dialog',
    components: {DialogBase,NewCarDialog},
    props: {
        redirectionReason: {String, default: null}
    },
    mixins: [WebsocketClient],
    data() {
        return {
            username: "",
            password: "",
            carType: {
                id: null,
                name: "",
            },
            car: {
                licensePlate: "",
            },
            confirm_password: "",
            email: "",
            phoneNumber: "",
            name: "",
            new_car_dialog:false,
            show: false,
            snackBar: false,
            snackbarText: "",
            tabsidx: 0,
          
        }
    },
    computed: {
       ...
    },
    methods: {
        ...
        onWebsocketEvent(message) {
            this.updateBatteryPercentage(message.batteryPercentage);
        },
        async load_data() {
            const person_response = await this.axios.get(`/api/person/current-person`);
            if (person_response.status === 200) {
                this.name = person_response.data.name;
                this.email = person_response.data.email;
                this.username = person_response.data.username;
                this.phoneNumber = person_response.data.phoneNumber;
                this.carType = person_response.data.car.carType;
                this.car = person_response.data.car;
            }
        },
        ...
    },
    async mounted() {
        await this.load_data();
        this.connect("carBatteryChange", this.car.id);
    },
};
</script>

<style>
.v-input {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

...

</style>
```

[image]

I would like that /api/person/current-person http request mock out with a mock response, so I in my component test I could check if the data is displayed properly.

Profile.spec.js

```js
describe("ProfileDialog", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mount(
      {
        vuetify,
        render(h) {
          return h(ProfileDialog, {
            methods: {
              async load_data() {
                console.log("THIS NEVER CALLED");
                const person_response = {
                  id: 8,
                  name: "myname",
                  username: "myname",
                  password: null,
                  email: "email@email.com",
                  phoneNumber: "701234567",
                  roles: [
                    {
                      id: 1,
                      name: "role_user",
                    },
                  ],
                  car: null,
                };
              },
            },
          });
        },
      },
      { extensions: { plugins: [Vuetify] } }
    );

    cy.wait(1000);
  });

  it("checks if profile data is fetched properly", () => {
    cy.wait(5000);
  });
});
```

Actually i tried many solutions to mock this request, but I am stucked and can not make this work.

By the way, every axios request is intercepting with a guard:

```js
const hasRightForPage = async (to) => {
    const response = await Vue.prototype.axios.post(`/api/hasRightForPage`,{
        route: to.path
    });

    return response.data;
}

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const resp = await hasRightForPage(to);

    if (resp === 'hasRight')
        next();
    else if(resp === 'tokenExpired')
        next({
            path: '/login',
        });
    else
        next(false);
});
```

In my cypress test I always got: Error: Request failed with status code 404
[image]

Hope someone can point me in the right direction how could I fake this api call, to test my component is displaying the current user's data (which is coming from the http response)

Comment: How did you intercept? This worked fine for me

Comment: can you share with me source code, maybe my implementation was bad.

Comment: it's just the same code as in cy.intercept's documentation

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a Cypress intercept? Let the axios call from the app proceed and intercept with a [staticResponse](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#With-a-StaticResponse-object) in Cypress.

```js
before(() => {
  cy.intercept('/api/person/current-person', {
    id: 8,
    name: "myname",
    ...
  })
  mount(...)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This repo is for React component tests, but for `cy.intercept` things are the same. Here are some Axios examples:

https://github.com/muratkeremozcan/multi-stage-caching/tree/master/cypress/component/network